# Why is this Meta Embed Image not showing?

Tags: html, embed, meta-tags

Why is this Meta Embed Image not showing when sharing the site link? It used to work but suddenly stopped for some reason

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Site List">
<meta property="og:description" content="Something">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta name="og:image" itemprop="image" content="https://spiritaxolotl.github.io/images/faces/spax/Smirk.png">
```